# Netty 5 HexDumpProxy issue

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I am facing some problem in `HexDumpProxy` usage. I am using netty lib netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar.

In `HexDumpProxyInitializer` class's `initChannel` method, I am having

```
@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {        
    ChannelPipeline cp = ch.pipeline();        
    cp.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));    
    cp.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
    cp.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());        
    cp.addLast(new HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler(remoteHost, remotePort));
}
```

and in `HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler` class, I want to process the incoming message as follows,
here I am converting `Object msg` to `String` and want to change the value, and facing problem in sending modified string.

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    String s1 = ((ByteBuf) msg).toString(Charset.defaultCharset());
    if (outboundChannel.isActive()) {
        outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(s1).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                if (future.isSuccess()) {
                    // was able to flush out data, start to read the next
                    // chunk
                    ctx.channel().read();
                    } else {
                    future.channel().close();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I am sending object itself without any modification, its working fine. But if I want to send `String`, its not throwing any exception, also not working.

After that I have enabled `String` encoder and decoder in `initChannel` method, then I am getting the following error,

```
Proxying *:9999 to 192.168.1.27:8554 ...
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf
    at ivz.proxy.HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.channelRead(HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:320)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:320)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:452)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:346)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:794)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Except the above mentioned methods, I have not changed anything in the code. So, my problem is, I want to change some values in `Object msg` before sending to server, How can I achive this? Or in other words, is it possible to send `String` in `writeAndFlush` method?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the logic behind outboundChannel part, but I think there are couple of issues with your code

```
 cp.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));    
 cp.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
 cp.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());        
 cp.addLast(new HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler(remoteHost, remotePort));
```

1. Since you have `StringDecoder` before HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler, so object received in the channelRead will be always String,

   When you write the String object back, it will be encoded to ByteBuff by StringEncoder.
2. In ChannelFutureListener implementation, no need to call `ctx.channel().read()`

   Netty will automatically call your handler's `channelRead()` method

**Update**:

channel().read() is required if you want to throttle/control the reads, to do that you have set auto read false in channel options, by default auto read is true.

Comment: Thank you for short note Jestan Nirojan. Very first, Before asking question here, I was just trying to convert that object into String and want to see whether I can write or not, after that I was thinking to alter the string and send it. 1> Now I have clearly understand the process. I am using this to test Rtsp with Live555MS as server and vlc as a client.

Comment: If I remove decoder/encoder in pipeline conf, HDProxy works fine, but As I mentioned, I want to change some value in the request, so I want to use decoder/encoder but HDProxy is not throwing any error after the changes as you told but its not working. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: 2> I have taken this project from netty5 example. So I was not aware before why there have written this **ctx.channel().read()**.

Comment: channel().read() is required if you want to throttle/control the reads, to do that you have set auto read false in channel options, by default auto read is true.

Comment: If you change String s1 = ((ByteBuf) msg).toString(Charset.defaultCharset()); to String s1 = (String) msg; it will work I think.

Comment: If I have enabled String Encoder/Decoder, request is arriving but not at all passed to server, If there is no String Encoder/Decoder everything is working fine and vlc is able to play video.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late, but I also struggled with this.
So here is how I solved it for my case.
In the `HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler` class I made the following changes to `channelActive()`:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();
    // Start the connection attempt.
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop()).channel(ctx.channel().getClass())
            .handler(new HexDumpProxyBackendHandler(inboundChannel))
            .option(ChannelOption.AUTO_READ, false);
    ChannelFuture f = b.connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
    outboundChannel = f.channel();
    outboundChannel.pipeline().addFirst(new StringDecoder());  // this 2 lines
    outboundChannel.pipeline().addFirst(new StringEncoder());
    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                // connection complete start to read first data
                inboundChannel.read();
            } else {
                // Close the connection if the connection attempt has
                // failed.
                inboundChannel.close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So after that, in the `channelRead` callbacks (for HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler and HexDumpProxyBackendHandler), the messages will be `String`